# Multiple sounds + watermark overlay not working with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a problem with an ffmpeg command.

I want to add the **same sound several times** in the final video and then **add a watermark above**.

When I do the full command, it doesn't work correctly because the sound is only played once (the first reference):

> ffmpeg -i "assets/frame%05d.png" -i "assets/sound.mp3" -loop 1 -i
> "assets/watermark.png" -filter_complex
> "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[s1];[1:a]adelay=3000|3000[s2];[s1][s2]amix=2[a];[0:v][2:v]overlay=shortest=1[outv]"
> -map "[outv]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -y "result.mp4"

When I don't add the watermark, it works correctly:

> ffmpeg -i "assets/frame%05d.png" -i "assets/sound.mp3" -filter_complex
> "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[s1];[1:a]adelay=3000|3000[s2];[s1][s2]amix=2[a]"
> -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -y "result.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i "assets/frame%05d.png" \
       -stream_loop -1 -i "assets/sound.mp3" \
       -loop 1 -i "assets/watermark.png" \
       -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[s1];\
                        [1:a]adelay=3000|3000[s2];\
                        [s1][s2]amix=2[a];\
                        [0:v][2:v]overlay=shortest=1[outv]" \
       -map "[outv]" -map "[a]" -shortest \
       -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -y "result.mp4"
```

`-stream_loop -1` input option loops the input infinitely and `-shortest` output option stops the audio when video is done.

p.s., I think an `aecho` filter can combine the 2nd `adelay` and `amix` filters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was that the different frames that make up the video were not all correctly encoded which caused the problem with the sounds.

**ffmpeg can't read indexed PNG correctly.**

You must therefore use this option (for those like me who use imagick):

```
$imagick->setOption('png:color-type', 6);
$imagick->writeImage('frame00000.png');
```